# Регулярное выражение для записи числа в любой системе счисления

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для записи числа в любой системе счисления.

1. Число может быть со знаком (- или +), либо без знака.
2. Число может быть целым или дробным (, или .)
3. Допустимые символы 0-9, A-Z.

Только начал с ними разбираться. До этого разбирал все в коде. Но это как-то топорно выходило.

---

У меня ограничение - от двоичной до 36-ичной

Comment: А почему A-Z ? или прям совсем любая система счисления?

Comment: Я думаю, что потом, если надо будет то добавлю еще символов для записи в системе с большим основанием. Надо хотя бы начать и вот это вот сделать. И уже буду пробовать разбираться. Пока сложно во все въехать

Comment: @splash58: A-Z хватит лишь на 36-ричную, для больших оснований букв не хватит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[-+]?[0-9A-Z]+[.,]?[0-9A-Z]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

для начала, например, вот так

```
^(\+|-)?[0-9A-Z]+([.,][0-9A-Z]+)?$
```

[Демо и немного объяснений](https://www.regex101.com/r/mF2wT9/1)

Comment: "(\+|-)*" зачем там "*"? Под вашу регулярку подойдет "--------+++++++----432". Вместо `*` - `?`.

Comment: Так же в конце - * после последних скобок разрешит `123.123.123`. И в начале и в конце используйте `?`

Comment: `[-+]?[0-9A-Z]+([.,][0-9A-Z]+)?` вот так точно правильно будет. потому как там еще запятая может быть вместо точки

Comment: Да конечно, зарапортовался  :)

Comment: @Mike давайте, вы ответ напишите, а то мне уже неудобно под своей фамилией это писать :)

Comment: @splash58 Да ладно вам, дело житейское :)

Comment: [-+]?[0-9A-Z]+([.,][0-9A-Z]+)?

Вот это подошло. Спасибо. Как оказалось, разобраться не сложно. Может посоветуете, с чего начать изучение регулярок, книгу какую

Comment: `1.` - не пройдёт.

Answer (score -1):

```
[-+]?[0-9A-Z]+([.,][0-9A-Z]+)?
```

Вот это подошло. Спасибо. Как оказалось, разобраться не сложно.

Comment: Книгу ... А википедия не подходит ? по моему там отлично все возможности описаны, а остальное это опыт. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы всегда можете оставлять комментарии под **своими** вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/53791)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это ответ, вынесен из комментария Mike: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480647/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/480649#comment552030_480650

Comment: @PashaPash: Это по сути вопрос о книгах по регуляркам. Тем более, что есть принятый ответ.

Comment: @VladD я вырезал упоминание про книги (надеюсь, DLiner не против). Почему он принял другой ответ - непонятно. Может быть тоже подошел, а система в течении трех дней не позволяет выбрать свой ответ как правильный. Тем не менее - это правильный ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, по модулю ужасной попытки локализации, учитывающей всего два языка — правильный.

Comment: В моем проекте локализация не важна. Точка и запятая всем понятна, думаю

Comment: @DLiner: Запятая — это специфический для России (и Германии, и ещё нескольких европейских стран) разделитель целой и дробной части, англоязычная традиция запятую не использует никогда. Так что учёт запятой — это попытка локализации по сути. Для реальной локализации вам придётся учитывать вскую экзотику наподобие тайских цифр и итальянского разделения на тройки разрядов апострофом.

Comment: @VladD, пока так глубоко копать не буду ). Может потом когда-нибудь. Мне кажется, что тайцы и т.д. не знают даже букв A..Z. Да и в планах сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам ставил символы для обозначения любой цифры в 36+ системе счисления. Да и вопрос использования . или , это можно в справке прописать

Comment: @DLiner: Ну это только два примера, на самом деле всё намного сложнее.